# Node express | When I get an error at any stage I need to disconnect redis

Tags: express, redis, middleware

I have a row of middlewares and the first one connects to redis

```
router.get( '/wasup', middleware1, middleware2, middleware3 )
```

At some point, I can get an error and if I do I need to disconnect redis. Is there some easy way how to implement it?

For now, what I see, I can do it in the catch block but in this case, I will need to add it to each middleware

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, you need to add to your last middleware an error as the first argument. But there is one thing if everything goes well and each middleware didn't throw an error, **disconnectRedisMiddleware** will be not run

```
function disconnectRedisMiddleware(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err) {
    client.quit();
  }
  next();
}

router.get('/wasup', middleware1, middleware2, middleware3, disconnectRedisMiddleware);
```